# Unable to reach firebase database on some internet connections

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database since 2 years in one of my app and that was working fine but since 28-march-2020 users are unable to access firebase database on some internet connection. but if they use vpn they can connect normally.
Any help would be appreciated.